# How to fix iText's text wrapping for chinese characters

Tags: java, localization, itext

I'm converting a document to support Chinese characters. But I'm getting strange text wrapping results. I'm loading the Chinese font with this code:

```
BaseFont.createFont("MSung-Light", "UniCNS-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

However, I'm getting orphaned punctuation marks like this:

[image: Orphaned punctuation in Chinese font]

I've tried embedding specific Chinese fonts, and using different encoding such as BaseFont.IDENTITY_H. I'm not having any trouble at all getting the characters to appear, but I can't find a way to get them to wrap correctly.

According to the language specialist at my company this is not normal, but I haven't been able to find any resources that tell me how to correct this.

#### EDIT

Yesterday I found the change logs that indicate there were text-wrapping fixes implemented in iText 5. As a result I upgraded from 5.2 to 5.4, but I'm still seeing the odd wrapping.

Comment: Wrapping is controled by an implementation of the `SplitCharacter` interface. As far as I know, there is a `DefaultSplitCharacter` class that takes into account Chinese characters in iText since iText 5. Which version of iText are you using? If the `DefaultSplitCharacter` doesn't work for your text, you can always provide your own `SplitCharacter` implementation.

Comment: I found a change log yesterday that mentioned that, so I upgraded to 5.4. I think I was running 5.2 before that. Unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything though. But thanks for the tip on SplitCharacter!